Android App Crashes with Fatal Signal 6 (SIGABRT) During Network Request
I'm encountering a recurring crash in my Android application when performing a network request. The crash log indicates a fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) in the DefaultDispatch thread. Below is the relevant portion of the log:
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22719 (DefaultDispatch)
--> GET https:
--> END GET
pid: 22581, tid: 22719, name: DefaultDispatch  >>> com.. <<<
    #05 pc 004cf89b  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #06 pc 00497e21  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #07 pc 00497e95  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #08 pc 00497e9d  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #09 pc 004974cb  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #10 pc 002008cb  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #11 pc 001e44dd  /data/app/com..-2/base.apk (offset 0x42ab000)
    #12 pc 0277f29d  /data/app/com..-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x2598000)

Application Details:
Package Name: com..
Network Request: GET request to ...
Thread: DefaultDispatch
Observation

The crash occurs consistently during the network request.
The stack trace points to specific offsets within the application's code, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause.
The application utilizes the Volley library for network operations.

private fun fetchSchedules(hardwareId: String) {
    val url = "https://hardwareID=$hardwareId"
    val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        { response ->
            // Handle successful response
        },
        { error ->
            // Handle error
        }
    )
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request)
}


Steps Taken

Verified that the URL is correct and accessible.
Ensured that the hardwareId parameter is valid.
Checked for any unhandled exceptions in the code.
Monitored memory usage to rule out leaks or excessive consumption.

Questions:

What could be causing the SIGABRT crash during the network request?
How can I map the offsets in the stack trace to specific lines in my source code?
Are there any best practices for handling network requests to prevent such crashes?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Especially since Volley has not been maintained in a while, have you tried something that is up to date and actively maintained, such as OkHttp or Ktor? Also, did you add the INTERNET permission request to your manifest?
